# $\varphi^4$ via renormalization group with hard cut-off

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, regularization, critical-phenomena

I am studying the application of the renormalization group to the $\varphi^4$ theory:

$$\mathcal{L} = -\frac{1}{2} \varphi (\Box + m^2)\varphi -\frac{\lambda}{4!}\varphi^4.$$

In particular I wanted to follow two different regularization methods, and verify that the resulting critical exponents $\nu$ did not differ, as I expect.

If you want to calculate the contributions up to one loop, you encounter two diagrams which diverge: the tadpole for the 2-points correlation function, and the loop for the 4-points correlation function. The first goes like $\int \frac{d^4k}{k^2-m^2}$, the second like $\int \frac{d^4k}{(k^2-m^2)^2}$.

In every textbook I know (e.g. Schwartz, Quantum Field Theory and the Standard Model, 23.5.1), you see the treamtment of the $\varphi^4$ and of the renormalization group with the dimensional regularization, which leads to the following equations:

$$\beta = -\varepsilon\lambda + \frac{3\lambda^2}{16\pi^2}$$

$$\mu\frac{d}{d\mu}m^2 = \frac{\lambda}{16\pi^2}m^2$$

where $\mu$ is the renormalization scale, $\lambda$ and $m^2$ are the renormalized constant of interaction and mass, and $d=4-\varepsilon$ is the dimension.

Solving for the Wilson-Fisher fixed point, we find $\lambda^* = \frac{16\pi^2\varepsilon}{3}$ and $m^{2*} =0$.

At the fixed point, the anomalous dimension of the mass is then $\gamma_m=\frac{\lambda^{*}}{16\pi^2}=\frac{\varepsilon}{3}$ giving $\nu=\frac{1}{2-\gamma_m}=\frac{3}{6-\varepsilon}$.

Fine. Now, if I try to introduce an explicit cut-off $\Lambda$ in the divergent integrals, in four dimensions I get something like:
$\int \frac{d^4k}{k^2-m^2} \propto \frac{\Lambda^2}{m^2} + \log(1+\frac{\Lambda^2}{m^2})$

$$\int \frac{d^4k}{(k^2-m^2)^2} \propto \log(1+\frac{\Lambda^2}{m^2}).$$

This is something worrisome, since we have two very different behaviours between the two integrals, and in the critical exponent they enter as a ratio.

But let's get into the calculation. I switch to the Euclidean integrals, and I define:

$f(\Lambda,m^2,d) = \int_\Lambda \frac{d^dk}{k^2+m^2}$

and

$g(\Lambda,m^2,d) = \int_\Lambda \frac{d^dk}{(k^2+m^2)^2}$

Taking into account that

$\Lambda \frac{d}{d\Lambda} f(\Lambda,m^2,d) = S_d \frac{\Lambda^d}{\Lambda^2+m^2} + \frac{\partial f(\Lambda,m^2,d)}{\partial m^2}\Lambda \frac{d}{d\Lambda}m^2$

and

$\Lambda \frac{d}{d\Lambda} g(\Lambda,m^2,d) = S_d \frac{\Lambda^d}{(\Lambda^2+m^2)^2} + \frac{\partial g(\Lambda,m^2,d)}{\partial m^2}\Lambda \frac{d}{d\Lambda}m^2$,

where $S_d$ is the area of the d-dimensional unit sphere,

I obtain the following equations for d-dimensions:

$\beta = -(4-d)\lambda - \frac{3}{2^{d+1}\pi^d}\lambda^2(-(4-d)f + \frac{\Lambda^d}{\Lambda^2+m^2}S_d)$

$\Lambda\frac{d}{d\Lambda}m^2 = -\frac{\lambda}{2^{d+1}\pi^d}m^2 (-(4-d)g + \frac{\Lambda^d}{(\Lambda^2+m^2)^2}S_d)$

If I now try to evaluate $\gamma_m$ at the fixed point, I find something like:

$\gamma_m = \frac{4-d}{3}\frac{-(4-d)g + \frac{\Lambda^d}{(\Lambda^2+m^2)^2}S_d}{-(4-d)f + \frac{\Lambda^d}{\Lambda^2+m^2}S_d}$

If I did not make any error, which is an assumption, that $\gamma_m$ is not equivalent to the one obtained via dimensional regularization. I am probably missing something.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**: I realized (thanks @TehMeh) that I defined the functions $f$ and $g$ differently from my pen and paper calculation, and came up with a mixed notation and a lot of mess, which ended up in a lot of errors. Sorry to everyone. Let me now correct.

$f(\Lambda,m^2,d) = \int_\Lambda \frac{d^dk}{(k^2+m^2)^2}$

and

$g(\Lambda,m^2,d) = \frac{1}{m^2}\int_\Lambda \frac{d^dk}{k^2+m^2}$

Taking into account that

$\Lambda \frac{d}{d\Lambda} f(\Lambda,m^2,d) = S_d \frac{\Lambda^d}{(\Lambda^2+m^2)^2} + \frac{\partial f(\Lambda,m^2,d)}{\partial m^2}\Lambda \frac{d}{d\Lambda}m^2$,

and

$\Lambda \frac{d}{d\Lambda} g(\Lambda,m^2,d) = \frac{S_d}{m^2} \frac{\Lambda^d}{\Lambda^2+m^2} + \frac{\partial g(\Lambda,m^2,d)}{\partial m^2}\Lambda \frac{d}{d\Lambda}m^2$

where $S_d$ is the area of the d-dimensional unit sphere,

I obtain the following equations for d-dimensions:

$\beta = -(4-d)\lambda - \frac{3}{2^{d+1}\pi^d}\lambda^2(-(4-d)f + \frac{\Lambda^d}{(\Lambda^2+m^2)^2}S_d)$

$\Lambda\frac{d}{d\Lambda}m^2 = -\frac{\lambda}{2^{d+1}\pi^d}m^2 (-(4-d)g + \frac{\Lambda^d}{\Lambda^2+m^2}\frac{S_d}{m^2})$

If I now try to evaluate $\gamma_m$ at the fixed point, I find something like:

$\gamma_m = \frac{4-d}{3}\frac{-(4-d)g + \frac{\Lambda^d}{\Lambda^2+m^2}\frac{S_d}{m^2}}{-(4-d)f + \frac{\Lambda^d}{(\Lambda^2+m^2)^2}S_d}$

$f$ and $g$ are representable with the hypergeometric function, but if we take the limit for small $4-d$ it should not anyway matter their expression.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 2):

I've been doing the very same problem (23.6 - right?), hopefully, this is still helpful.

First of all, I notice that your $\beta$ function is probably incorrect. In $d=4$ it should be dimensionless and yet one of the terms is of mass dimension 2, which is also different from the two other terms.
If you fix that, maybe in $d=4-\epsilon$ dimensions your $\gamma_m$ is correct once expanded in $\epsilon$ as you have the seemingly correct prefactor of $\frac{4-d}{3}$, which would immediately give the correct answer.

I myself did the problem in a slightly different manner.
We have to work in $d=4-\epsilon$ dimensions and I introduced the usual subtraction point $\mu$, also there were no $\epsilon$ poles as these are regulated by the cut off $\Lambda$.
To get $\beta$ functions I differentiated bare parameters with respect to $\mu$, for example,

$\mu \frac{d\lambda_0}{d\mu}=\mu \frac{d(\lambda_R \mu^{\epsilon}(\mu)Z_\lambda)}{d\mu}$

Where $\lambda_R(\mu)$ is the renormalized coupling and $Z_\lambda=1+\delta_\lambda$ is the renormalization constant - all as in Schwartz. I got the counterterms by expanding the integrands in powers of $m^2$ and keeping only divergent (after integration) terms.
The counterterms are quite nasty due to $\epsilon$ and the regulator $\lambda$, hence, I used Mathematica to do expansions and solve for $\beta$ functions. In the end, the result matches the one from dimensional regularization.

Comment: Good point on the dimension of $\beta$, I did not reread properly what I wrote here... I made a pretty big mess in my writing up there... When I have time I will edit it, but I think the issue still remains with this method. I left out a $m^{-2}$ from one function, and swapped the two, but the argument shall remain the same. Regarding your method, how did you treat the integral in $d=4-\varepsilon$ dimensions?

Comment: I also went for the Euclidean integrals, so that only one integration up to $\Lambda$ remains. 
Then I expanded the integrand and only kept the divergent parts. But that should not matter really, you can keep the finite parts too.
At this point, I also expanded the integrand in $\epsilon$ up to first order (do not forget the volume in $d=4-\epsilon$ dimensions when expanding.)
Integrate. 
Logarithms should get $\mu$'s.
Eventually, the counterterms should be something like $\delta= A + \epsilon B$, where $A$ and $B$ are divergent.
Does this answer your question?

Comment: I tried to replicate your calculation. Don't you end up anyway with a $\Lambda^2$ factor in $\gamma^{*}$? While the factor $\mu \frac{d \Lambda}{d \mu}$ luckily cancels, I still have a $\Lambda$ coming from the $\lambda^{*}$ and a $\Lambda$ from the $\mu \frac{d \delta_{m}}{d \mu}$.

Comment: Hi!
No, there are no remaining $\Lambda$'s.
Since $\beta$ functions are functions of couplings only, I do not see how $\gamma$ could have an explicit cut-off. So first check the $\beta$ functions. 
Also, not sure if it is just a typo on your end, but $\Lambda$ is independent of $\mu$, hence, $\mu \frac{d \Lambda}{d\mu}=0$.

Comment: The coupling $\lambda$ is basically an integral of a function of the moment up to the cut-off $\Lambda$, so in general it can be dependent from it. It could drop out, as in your case I guess, but incidentally. What am I missing? When you introduct $\mu$, you are basically moving from $\Lambda$ dependent couplings to $\mu$ dependent couplings; in this transformation, $\Lambda$ should in general become a function of $\mu$. Does this dependence drop out in your calculation? Maybe I am loosing myself in a glass of water...

Comment: Sorry, in the comment above I wrote "the coupling $\lambda$", but actually I was thinking about the counterterms $\delta_{\lambda}$ and $\delta_m$. They are in general dependent by $\Lambda$, and then they enter the $\beta$ functions.

Comment: Yes, the counterterms do depend on the cutoff (as well as the subtraction point $\mu$), but the $\beta$ functions explicitly depend only on the couplings - the cutoff dependence drops out. 

And no, the cutoff $\Lambda$ is independent of $\mu$, just like $\epsilon$ is independent of $\mu$ in dimreg.
By introducing this $\mu$ I try to get closer to what Schwartz is doing in his book - the regulator (be it $\epsilon$ or cutoff) is fixed and everything else depends on $\mu$. To be honest, I am not entirely sure how to compute without $\mu$.

Comment: Also, the regulator drops out of $\beta$ functions because of the $\mu$ derivatives.
The way I see it is that the genuine prediction of QFT are logarithms and only in these logarithms, one has $\mu$ dependence - be it in a ratio with a cutoff or some other relevant scale (like a mass). Since $\mu$ is in logarithms only, taking derivatives effectively gets rid of those additional scales. That is why counterterms do have regulator dependence and $\beta$ functions are free of that.

Comment: Let me explain my view. You have divergent integrals, which enter to the calculation of some observable. You tame it with a cut-off. With the hard cut-off I see two possibilities: you send it to infinity, or you leave it somehow undetermined by fixing a reference scale, but you must then trade it with a $\mu$ dependence. The first approach is the one in my post, extremely brute I admit (a Pauli-Villars approach could be a more sophisticated step), the second is yours.

Comment: Probably I am wrong, but if you trade $\Lambda$ for $\mu$, you still have a dependence from it. Otherwise, you should also consider the dependence of $\lambda$ on $\Lambda$, or you would be missing a piece from the renormalization group. Can you share your $\delta_{\lambda}$ and $\delta_{m}$?

Comment: Hmph, my view is a bit different. In my mind $\Lambda$ is related to theory itself, while $\mu$ is related to measurment. As I have said, I am not entirely sure, how renormalizatiion only with the cutoff works, but in simple terms I can measure my observables at whatever scale $\mu$ that I want without changing the regularizations. And inversly, the theory can cut itself off at whatever $\Lambda$ it likes and doesn't care at what $\mu$ I want to do my measurement.

Comment: So by introducing $\mu$ I am only introducing a physical scale at which I am computing, I am not trading it with $\Lambda$ or making $\Lambda$ depend on $\mu$. As you have said $\Lambda$ is fixed at some value meaning no variations, vanishing derivatives.

Comment: Maybe later I'll have the time to write down the counterterms

Answer (score 0):

Taking a derivative (with regard to a parameter) to a quadratically divergent integral
$$
\Lambda \frac{d}{d\Lambda} f(\Lambda,m^2,d) = S_d \frac{\Lambda^d}{\Lambda^2+m^2} + \frac{\partial f(\Lambda,m^2,d)}{\partial m^2}\Lambda \frac{d}{d\Lambda}m^2
$$
will open a can of worms (e.g. the order of $\partial m^2$ and $d^4k$ is not interchangeable) when hard cutoff is involved, albeit
$$
\Lambda \frac{d}{d\Lambda} g(\Lambda,m^2,d)
$$
is OK, since $g(\Lambda,m^2,d)$ is only logarithmically divergent.

The cutoff and boundary conditions are very tricky for divergent Feynman integrals beyond logarithmic divergence. A typical example is the triangular diagram (linearly divergent) of the ABJ anomaly, where seemingly innocuous shift of integrals are prohibited.

Comment: Ok, you mean that there could be potential boundary terms that I could be neglecting when exchanging the derivative with the integral, correct? But if I specialize the calculation to a particular case where the integral can be done analytically, taking into account all the boundary terms, e.g. d=3, I still come to the same conclusions.